# Does partitioning sometimes require denormalization?

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

Specific example of what I'm asking:

Say that a SaaS app has an **Order** table with *CustomerID* and a child **OrderItem** table.

We want to partition both tables and we want to use *CustomerID* as the partition key.

The issue is that the **OrderItem** table does not have a *CustomerID* column (its only foreign key is to the **Order** table).

Would it be a best-practice to denormalize the **OrderItem** table and add a *CustomerID* column to it for the sake of partitioning?

Comment: You can not Partition by something that is not included in the table. So yes if you wish to partition by CustomerID it will need to be in the table. Whether this is a best practice or not depends a ton on your table structure and whether or not you truly need partitioning.

Comment: Agreed with @Zane. Usually people partition by things that are more predictable in terms of growth and distribution, such as OrderDate. Sure orders by day or month will fluctuate, but partitioning by CustomerID is like partitioning by first letter of last name - your Q and X partitions are going to be pretty quiet, while your J and S partitions will be large and busy. Also, usually, partitioning allows you to do things like archive data (say, orders over 6 months old move to some near- or off-line resource). What maintenance advantage does partitioning by CustomerID buy you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you want to partition by CustomerID, then CustomerID must exist in the table (even if it is redundant).

But first, IMHO, you need to ask yourself a couple of questions:

1. Do I need partitioning? What am I using it for? What problem am I solving?
2. If the answer to 1. is yes, then am I partitioning on the right column? How - specifically - will partitioning on CustomerID help in my environment?

I find that a lot of people turn to partitioning as a knee-jerk reaction to a performance problem of some kind that partitioning simply can't (completely) solve.

Similar to indexed views - people create views on top of views on top of views, then assume that all they need to do is create an index on each view and that will speed everything up. Then they actually learn the hard way about what indexed views are, how they work, and the much more limited set of scenarios that comprise their "sweet spot."

Comment: Thanks Aaron. We are looking at partitioning to help with lock contention / deadlocks. We have a SaaS (multi-tenant) app; so partitioning by customer feels like the natural approach (more or less isolating each customer into their own filegroup, where one customer's locks won't affect another customer).